# Integrate $\int{ \frac{u}{(R^2 + r^2 - 2Rru)^{1/2}} du}$

Tags: integration

I am stuck at  this integration. Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering $$I=\int{ \frac{u}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2 - 2Rru}} du}$$ change variable $$R^2 + r^2 - 2Rru=t^2\implies u=\frac{r^2+R^2-t^2}{2 r R}\implies du=-\frac{t}{r R}$$ All of that makes $$I=-\int\frac{r^2+R^2-t^2}{2 r^2 R^2}\,dt$$ which seems simple to integrate.